# Does an automorphism map an endomorphism applied to a basis to the same endomorphism applied to another basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

A question inspired by Steven Roman's *Advanced Linear Algebra*:

Let $V$ be a vector space, $\sigma$ an automorphism on $V$ and $\tau$ an endomorphism on V.

We know $\sigma$ maps any basis of $V$ into a basis of $V$.

Now let $B =\{b_i\}$ be an ordered basis of $V$.

My question is: does there always exist an ordered basis of $V$, call it $C =\{c_i\}$, such that $\sigma$ maps $\tau(b_i)$ into $\tau(c_i)$ for each $i$?

Comment: What about the zero endomorphism?

Comment: Then it's trivially true, no?

Comment: It's trivially false: the basis will all be collapsed to the zero vector, which is not a basis.

Comment: I think your title question is different from your punchline question.

Comment: Then I'll just remove the punchline as you call it. I think the question before it reads the same as the title, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is not true for every order basis $B$ of $V$. 
Since $\tau$ is an endomorphism, there could be the case that 
$(\sigma \circ \tau)(b_i)$ is not in the image under 
$\tau$.